# How to find a new equidistant vector, given 5 existing vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, linear-transformations, python

Vectors v1, v2, v3, v4, V5, with 100 dim each, how to find a center vector, that will have equal distance with each?

preferably if there is a way done in Python or Numpy.

Comment: What do you mean by equal distance? Do you mean having the same magnitude as the sum of the vectors? Or something else?

Comment: @Carser, so distance between 2 vectors, is d(u⃗ ,v⃗ )=SQRT((u1−v1)2+(u2−v2)2...(un−vn)2), using Euclidean distance. Therefore am looking to find a Vector thats its distance is the same when computing between this Vector and other vectors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that if the distances are all equal, then the squares of the distances are also equal. This avoids needing to use square roots, making the handling more efficient & easier to deal with.

Consider a general case where you have $n$ vectors, each of $d$ dimensions, with $v_c$ being the center vector you want to determine. Notation wise, have $v_{ji}$ be the $i$'th component of vector $v_j$. The distance squared from the first vector to the center vector is to be the same as the distance squared from every other vector to the center vector, i.e.,

$$\sum_{i = 1}^d \left(v_{1i} - v_{ci}\right)^2 = \sum_{i = 1}^d \left(v_{ji} - v_{ci}\right)^2 \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

for all $2 \le j \le n$. Expanding the squares inside the summations and moving various parts around gives

$$\sum_{i = 1}^d \left(v_{1i}^2 - 2v_{1i}v_{ci} + v_{ci}^2\right) = \sum_{i = 1}^d \left(v_{ji}^2 - 2v_{ji}v_{ci} + v_{ci}^2\right)$$
$$\sum_{i = 1}^d \left(v_{1i}^2 - v_{ji}^2 - 2v_{1i}v_{ci} + 2v_{ji}v_{ci}\right) = 0$$
$$\sum_{i = 1}^d \left(v_{1i}^2 - v_{ji}^2\right) - 2\sum_{i = 1}^d \left(v_{1i} - v_{ji}\right)v_{ci} = 0$$
$$2\sum_{i = 1}^d \left(v_{1i} - v_{ji}\right)v_{ci} = \sum_{i = 1}^d \left(v_{1i}^2 - v_{ji}^2\right) \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

Since the $v_{1i}$ and $v_{ji}$ values are known, \eqref{eq2} is simply a linear equation in the $d$ unknowns of $v_{ci}$. Using $j$ from $2$ to $n$ gives you $n-1$ such equations to solve simultaneously. In your particular case, $d = 100$ and $n = 5$ means you have a very under-determined system of $4$ equations in $100$ unknowns, so there won't be a unique center vector. Regarding solving this in Python, there are several possible ways to do it using packages like numpy and sympy, such as described in [Is there a python module to solve linear equations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6789927/is-there-a-python-module-to-solve-linear-equations).

Update: As pointed out in a comment by [Théophile](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/26091/th%c3%a9ophile), with so many available degrees of freedom, you can reasonably impose some constraints, such as required or suggested by the problem, with the suggested option being to

> find the solution with the smallest magnitude, i.e., closest to the origin.

Comment: Given that the system will be under-determined, one could find the solution with the smallest magnitude, i.e., closest to the origin. (This may or may not be useful, depending on the context of the question.)

Comment: @Théophile Thanks for your suggestion. I incorporated it into an update to my answer.