# how to find the centre vector in a multi-dimensional space full of vectors

Tags: vectors, python

I am trying to find the centre vector in a multi-dimensional space full of vectors. The vector points have 100+ dimensions and I would like to find the centre so that I can use the centre vector to represent the overall vector space.

I have looked at calculating the mean of the vectors but as I am unable to plot the vectors, I can't confirm that they are all evenly spread out. If the vectors are not evenly spread out then this would affect the mean, it would be skewed.

My maths isn't the greatest so if you could explain the solution in the simplest way possible.

My question is, how can this be done in Python as I will be using the output to calculate the cosine similarity between the centre and another set of vectors to find similar points between the first and second vector group.

Comment: Please remind me, what is a centre vector?

Comment: A vector that can fairly represent all the other vectors. As the centre vector is the same distance to every vector.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find a new equidistant vector, given 5 existing vectors?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3203273/how-to-find-a-new-equidistant-vector-given-5-existing-vectors)